# For loop not printing everything from a list in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why is this for loop not printing everything in this list/array? For example, the list `sentence` has the values `[0, 2]` but it's only printing out `0`

```
# this variable is global, meaning it can be used everywhere.
numbers = []

def looping(number, increment):
    i = 0
    while i < number:
        print "At the top of i is %d" % i
        numbers.append(i)

        i = i + increment
        print "Numbers now: ", numbers
        print "At the bottom of i is %d" % i


looping(2, 2)

print "The numbers: "

for num in numbers:
    print num
```

Comment: Because `i + 2 (increment)` breaks the `while i < number (2)` loop.

Comment: 2 is not less than 2, so 2 doesn't get appended to `numbers`.

Answer (score 1):

you need `while i <= number:` not `while i < number:`

Comment: Thank you! But I don't understand why this is the problem?

Comment: Because the for loop will stop if it's greater than the number but not equal to the number. For example `0 is less than 2`, `1 is less than 2`, `2 is not less than 2 don't run while loop`

Comment: you are increment thought the numbers by 2 and you are asking if it is less then 2. 2 is not less then 2 but 2 is less then or equal to 2. @JordanBaron